# Parent process exits twice using fork() execv() in c++

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, fork

I have a multiprocessing application that works well, except the parent process seems to exit twice.

I left out some of the code for simplification. Basically, I use libcurl (I wrote my own abstraction layer for it) to get JSON data from a server (left the code for this out) and then the simdjson library to iterate through it and run worker processes where required.

At the end I wait for all child processes (in the parent process) to terminate before printing "done". I can see however, that my program is printing "done" twice. I presume once after it's done in the for loop to create all the worker processes and then again once the last child returns. At least that is what I can see from the output on the console, as the child processes print to the console as well. However, given that I use `if (pid_fork > 0)`, i.e. I must be in the parent process, any subsequent code should be executed only once. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "simdjson.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    /* some other code */
    
    pid_t pid_fork;
    std::vector<int> v_pid;

    // loop through json
    for (simdjson::dom::element mq_item : json_mq_items)
    {
        pid_fork = fork();
        if (pid_fork == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "error: could not fork process" << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else if (pid_fork > 1) // parent process
        {
            v_pid.push_back(pid_fork);
        }
        else // child process (pid_fork == 0)
        {
            char *argv[] = { (char*)(std::string("foo")), NULL };
            if (execv((static_cast<std::string>("./foo")).c_str(), argv) == -1)
            {
                std::cout << "could not load child" << std::endl;
                return EXIT_FAILURE;                    
            }
        }
    }

    // in parent process only
    if (pid_fork > 0)
    {
        // Wait for all child processes to terminate

        for (size_t i = 0; i < v_pid.size(); i++) 
        {
            while (waitpid(v_pid[i], NULL, 0) > 0);
        }

        /* some other code */

        std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `(char*)(std::string("foo"))` What? This looks very wrong!

Comment: If there is more than one item in`json_mq_items`, and launching the child succeeds on the first iteration, both parent and child proceed into the second iteration of the loop and each launches a child.   So, as far as that first child is concerned, it is a parent - so it will wait on its children and print `Done`.   Then the original parent waits on all its children (including the first child that is waiting on children) and then print `Done`.     Depending on your data set (which you have not shown) you may get multiple children becoming parents .....

Comment: Your `argv` contains a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Peter `execv()` shouldn't return into the original code in case of success. (The code is replaced then.)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I made an [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ee81ed9db1b0c95) but I couldn't reproduce your issue. Though, I fixed some strange string handling which I considered as wrong...

Comment: `else if (pid_fork > 1) // parent process` has a smell as well although I consider it as very unlikely that 1 will be ever returned. ;-)